# Effective capacitance of a capacitor under DC-bias voltage

Tags: capacitor, bias

In my system, I charge a multi-layer ceramic capacitor between 3 V and 5 V using a buck converter. Once the voltage reaches 5 V, the capacitor starts discharging until it reaches 3 V, and the cycle repeats.

However, I require the capacitor to have a minimum capacitance of 60 μF when it starts discharging. Although I know that the capacitance decreases due to DC bias, I am uncertain about whether DC bias affects the voltage or the change in voltage. As the voltage change in my system is 2 V, should I determine the effective capacitance at 2 V DC-bias voltage, 3 V, or 5 V? The capacitor I am using has 100 μF at 0 V, 65 μF at 3 V, and 37 μF at 5 V.

Comment: Apparently there are SPICE models that model DC-bias impact.  I have no expericience with this issue, but energywise: E=CV^2/2.  \@5V:444uJ - \@3V:260uJ .  "I require minimum 60uF when it starts discharging" -> but @5V it is already much less.  As voltage is a result of the incoming charge, I'ld say DC-bias likely affects the change in the voltage for constant current - and it looks like the voltage rises faster with constant current into the capacitor (drops faster when the Cap provides the energy), while a perfect Cap has linear voltage change for a constant current.

Comment: There is no reason to use a 100 uF ceramic provided. Why is that?

Answer (score 20):

The DC bias derating of an MLCC is a product of something called "spontaneous polarisation reversal inhibition". This sounds complicated, but it's not super difficult to wrap your head around once you understand the physical principles involved.

Class II ceramic capacitors (most MLCCs other than C0G) are typically constructed from barium titanate crystals. The ions in these crystals are naturally (spontaneously) polarised in random orientations:

[image: Barium titanate crystals showing random orientations]

(if you'll excuse my crude mspaint job)

When you apply an external electric field, some of the crystals will change polarisation orientation to align with this field:

[image: Barium titanate crystals showing most crystals aligning thier polarities to an applied field]

(imagine there's an electric field going top to bottom - you can see that the polarisation has aligned with this field in most crystals)

Put simply: larger voltage across the capacitor = stronger electric field = more crystals with polarities aligned with the applied field.

The degree to which the crystals' polarities can be aligned by an external field can be described as the *relative permittivity* of the material. This is essentially where the capacitance arises from. When a voltage is applied across the capacitor, the resulting electric field starts to align the polarisation of the crystals, which is known as "reversing" the spontaneous polarisation.

Now, think about the relative permittivity of the capacitor, and therefore its capacitance, as being proportional to the number of crystals that are available to be aligned by an applied electric field. When there's no electric field, all of the crystals are in the randomly oriented spontaneous polarisation state, so most of them are available to be aligned by an applied field. The more crystals you polarise, the fewer there are left in the spontaneous polarisation state, which leaves you with less effective capacitance.

This is why the capacitance drops as the voltage across the capacitor increases - the electric field strength is proportional to the voltage across the capacitor. As you increase the voltage, you reverse more and more of the spontaneous polarisation, leaving fewer crystals in the spontaneous polarisation state, i.e. inhibiting the amount of spontaneous polarisation reversal that can occur.

This should start to answer your question: the DC bias derating is solely dependent on the strength of the electric field, which is a result of the voltage across the capacitor at any time: the *instantaneous* capacitance that a capacitor has is based on the voltage across it at that time.

In AC operation (bipolar, around a 0V bias), the direction of the electric field in the capacitor is continuously changing. When the voltage crosses 0V, all the crystals are in the spontaneous polarisation state. As the voltage increases in one direction, more crystals are polarised to align with the applied field. When the field reverses (i.e. the voltage changes polarity), crystals that were previously aligned in one direction can be re-aligned in the new direction. This results in a much lower degree of reversal inhibition than in DC operation.

However, if you take that same AC signal and apply a DC bias, e.g. a 1Vpk sine wave with a DC bias of 5V (i.e. going between 4V and 6V), that DC bias will cause many of the crystals to be polarised in the direction of the DC portion of the electric field. This reduces the number of crystals available in the spontaneous polarisation state, so the superimposed AC signal doesn't "see" as much capacitance due to the presence of the DC bias.

The *instantaneous* capacitance at any point in time is a result of the voltage across the capacitor at that instant (anywhere between 4V and 6V in our example), but the *average* capacitance over any timescale is a result of the average voltage over the capacitor during that time, which usually averages out the AC component to 0V and leaves only the DC component (5V in our example).

The actual physical behaviour at AC and DC is identical in this regard, but when we're analysing circuits it usually makes sense to think about the *average* capacitance as a result of the *average* DC voltage, which is equal to the DC offset (bias), which is why we talk about this effect in terms of DC bias.

You've said that you need 60μF when your capacitor starts discharging. This tells you that you need to care about the instantaneous, not average, voltage across the capacitor at that moment. Since your capacitor is charged to 5V at that moment, it has 5V over it, so the DC bias derating at 5V applies. Given your capacitor's DC bias derating specs, it will have 37μF of capacitance at that point in time, which is obviously not enough for your requirements.

Comment: Is this also the reason that larger package capacitors (e.g 1206) are less effected by DC bias than smaller ones (e.g. 0603) with the same nominal capacitance? There is simply more material for the polarisation?

Comment: @LarsHankeln Yes. The phenomenon is almost exclusively down to volume of the material. You can't fully tie it to the package code because that only gives you two dimensions, as there can be height variations (within reason - you're not going to find an 0603 that's 5mm tall), but package size does give a significant indicator of the amount of DC bias derating.

Answer (score 2):

You say you need the capacitor to have at least 60 uF at 5V.

You say the capacitor has 37 uF at 5V.

Therefore the capacitance at 5V matters for you, because that's the amount of charge the capacitor contains when discharge starts.

And then it does not match your requirement of having at least 60 uF at 5V.

The capacitor never has 0V or 2V bias so capacitance at 0V or 2V does not matter. 3V does not matter either, as that's the lowest voltage you require and at that voltage it can store enough charge to be a 65 uF capacitor.

At most a nominal capacitance at 4V could be important, as that's maybe the average voltage, but it is likely that in your setup the average voltage is not 4V, and the ripple is 2Vpp, so you really need to consider the capacitance at 5V to fit your requirements at 5V.

Answer (score 2):

The capacitance tells you the rate of change of capacitor voltage for any given current. It's inversely proportional to the slope of the voltage curve at a fixed current. So if you charged it at a constant current the voltage vs time curve would curve upward as the voltage increases.

What matters is the total voltage across the capacitor, not the change (of which it has not much memory).

Answer (score 2):

Capacitance "at" a voltage is measured as \$\mathrm {dQ}/\mathrm {dU}\$.  The charge stored between 5V and 3V will be \$\int_{3\mathrm V}^{5\mathrm V} C(u) \mathrm d u\$, the stored energy will be \$\int_{3\mathrm V}^{5\mathrm V} C(u)\,u\,\mathrm d u\$.  If your requirements state "minimum capacitance of 60uF", it probably refers to the expected stored energy assuming a *constant* capacitance, namely \$\frac12 (25\mathrm V^2-9\mathrm V^2)60\mathrm{\mu F}= 480\mathrm {\mu J}\$.  So that's what the above integral for the stored energy has to evaluate to when the capacitance is voltage-dependent.

Again, this is assuming that the \$60 \mathrm{\mu F}\$ specification has been made in order to warrant a certain energy differential to be available between 3V and 5V charge level.  If the specification is based on a different measure, you'll likely need to evaluate some other integral based on the voltage-dependent differential capacitance.

Answer (score 1):

Also, don't forget about capacitance derating as a function of temperature. This is independent of the voltage derating. You state that your voltage derating is -63% (only 37 uF remaining from 100 uF originally), so if your temperature derating is -20% at your worst case (usually highest, but check the curves), then at that temperature and voltage, you would actually only have (100uF x 0.37 x 0.80) = 29.6 uF.
Based on the voltage derating, it sounds like you are using a Z5U or Y5V dielectric, which have terrible temperature deratings. I would encourage you to look at an X7R or X5R dielectric, which have much better deratings with both temperature and voltage. Yes, for the same nominal 100uF, it will be physically larger, but due to better deratings, you might be able to get away with a single 100 uF cap, rather than two or three 100 uF Z5U caps to achieve an actual 60uF at 5V and max temp.

Answer (score 0):

> should I determine the effective capacitance at 2 V DC-bias voltage, 3 V, or 5 V? The capacitor I am using has 100 μF at 0 V, 65 μF at 3 V, and 37 μF at 5 V.

At 5V, since that's the worst case.

You need to either:

1. Use a better capacitor, e.g. X7R ceramic or tantalum.
2. Add a 2nd capacitor of equal value in parallel. Ideally, to have some margin of safety, you'd use three of those "100μF" capacitors in parallel.